# How do I interact with the virtual machine from Hyper-V host?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm running a hypervisor Hyper-V on server hardware. I exported two virtual machines from elsewhere and I want to start them here while disconnected from the LAN. I'm on a terminal session on the Hyper-V with Task Manager, command line and Powershell; I don't have a GUI interface. So I started them just fine using Start-VM from Powershell.

How do I interact with the virtual machine? Normally while on the LAN I remote into the VM. But now I'm disconnected from the LAN. How do I start a terminal session (or remote into) the VM?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Connection tool. The tool [can be installed easily](https://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php?title=The_Hyper-V_Virtual_Machine_Connection_Tool) on other servers and it uses the host to provide the connection to the guest, which gets around your no guest networking issue.

Comment: I don't have VMConnect.exe and I don't have a start button: I don't have Windows Server etc. I can't find the Connection Tool for download. I'm not sure if it can be installed.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe not possible to do what I want to do.

Comment: @D_Bester That doesn't make sense. You don't install this on your Hyper-V server, you install it on your local workstation, laptop, etc. It then connects from your computer to the Hyper-V server. That tutorial is extremely out of date though and doesn't really explain how to install the Hyper-V management tools on modern Windows. Try something like [this](https://petri.com/workaround-finding-missing-hyper-v-tools-windows-10).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well I guess you're agreeing with me then that it can't be done on the Hyper-V Server. Thanks for that confirmation. Remember, I don't have it on the network.

Comment: Your Hyper-V server should be on the network and nothing should be keeping you from putting it on the network. If you don't want your migrated guests to have any networking then just remove/disable the virtual NIC in the guest's machine config. This allows you to have the Hyper-V host on the network, the guests off the network, and then you to be able to use a tool like VMConnect to have remote console access.